# creating a generic static method in java

Tags: java, generics

I wanted to create a static method which prints the contents of an array.I wrote one for String[] as below

```
public static void print(String[] a){
    for(String x : a){
    System.out.print(x+", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

I thought I could create a method which takes in a generic type ,and modified the code as below

```
public class ArrayPrinting<E> {

    public static void printArray(E[] a){
        for(E x : a){
            System.out.print(x+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"A","B","C","D","E"};


    }
}
```

But,this gives a compiler error

> 'Cannot make a static reference to the non-static type E'

So,how do I create such a method?or is it impossible ? Since this is a static method, I wonder how I can invoke the method without creating an instance. A call like

`ArrayPrinting<E>.printArray(a)` doesn't look right ..

Can someone help?

Comment: Note that you can also use [`Arrays.toString`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString\(java.lang.Object[]\)) if you don't need the practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this

```
public class ArrayPrinting {

    public static <E> void printArray(E[] a){
        for(E x : a){
            System.out.print(x+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] a = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
        ArrayPrinting.printArray(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: That's it. If @damon needs a generic method, that's what he has to declare, not a generic type as in the question.

Answer (score 5):

Ravi already covered the proper syntax for a [generic method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). I just want to point out that this particular method doesn't need to be generic:

```
public static void printArray(Object[] a) {
    for (Object x : a) {
        System.out.print(x + ", ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

The reason this works is [array covariance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_%28computer_science%29#Covariant_arrays_in_Java_and_C.23) - a `String[]` is an `Object[]`.

Answer (score 1):

*Class's generic type parameters are for class level variables and methods (instance variables and methods).So you can't use it.*

You can handle it by declaring type parameter in the method itself:

```
  public static <E> void printArray(E[] a){
     .............
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

```
public class ArrayPrinting<E> {

    public  void printArray(E[] a){
        for(E x : a){
            System.out.print(x+", ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
          String[] a = {"A","B","C","D","E"};
          new ArrayPrinting().printArray(a);
    }
}
```

Comment: The OP wants a static method. And you're using a raw type.